# AJAX response with PHP, mysql issues

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I'm having some problems generating an AJAX response with PHP. The response should be a associative array with the database values inside. These values are displayed in a selectbox afterwards.

```
if (isset($_POST['rolle'])) {
    $sql = "SELECT rolle FROM pu_zugriff_rolle ORDER BY rolle ASC";

    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    $result = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

There are several entries stored in the database but I only get the first database value twice as a result. The sql query is definitively not the problem.

I read somewhere the `$result = my_sql_array($result);` statement is needed to create an assiciative array. If I'm leaving it the statement out, it results in an empty selectbox.

Comment: The [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) says: "mysql_fetch_array — Fetch **a result row** as an associative array, a numeric array, or both"

Comment: Why are you not following Safraz' advice from your previous question? The principle is the same, you need to run a loop (not my downvote though)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$finalArr = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $finalArr[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($finalArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use mysql_fetch_assoc($result) or MYSQL_ASSOC constant like mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);